# Always encounter "Ambari Server not running, Stale PID File at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid"

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, virtualbox, ambari

I am one new guy to learn Hadoop with ambari from apache, and I have been trying to install ambari on my Ubuntu in VirtualBox environment, however, I am exhausted by encountering the problem.

1stly, the system reminder me that "Ambari Server 'start' completed successfully" as following

```
~# ambari-server start
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
Starting ambari-server
Ambari Server running with administrator privileges.
Organizing resource files at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources...
Server PID at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid
Server out at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out
Server log at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log
Waiting for server start...................
Ambari Server 'start' completed successfully.
```

However, I cannot access ambari service via "http://127.0.0.1:8080", and when I check the server status as following

```
~# ambari-server status
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
Ambari-server status
Ambari Server not running. Stale PID File at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid
```

When I check the file of /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid

```
~# cat /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid 
2875
```

When I check into the log file, it leads with following lines

```
22 May 2015 10:59:42,876  INFO [main] Configuration:527 - Reading password from existing file
22 May 2015 10:59:43,073  INFO [main] Configuration:747 - Hosts Mapping File null
22 May 2015 10:59:43,074  INFO [main] HostsMap:60 - Using hostsmap file null
22 May 2015 10:59:45,169  INFO [main] ControllerModule:172 - Detected MYSQL as the database type from the JDBC URL
22 May 2015 10:59:45,253  INFO [main] ControllerModule:214 - Using c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource as the EclipsLink DataSource
22 May 2015 10:59:45,416  INFO [main] MLog:80 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
22 May 2015 10:59:46,124  INFO [main] C3P0Registry:204 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.1 [built 15-March-2007 01:32:31; debug? true; trace: 10]
22 May 2015 10:59:59,830 ERROR [main] DBAccessorImpl:99 - Error while creating database accessor 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I searched the internet, and found no solution for this issue.

By the way, I haven't installed Hadoop yet, whether this is the issue or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your `/etc/hosts` file in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked

Instead of running the command in background, I used `nohup`. It worked.
The content of the script which was executed in remote machine is given below.

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup ambari-server start
```

Comment: wtf?   the log file clearly states that there is a problem to communicate with mysql server: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.  What happen -> ambari server starts cleanly, initializing core, trying to connect to the database and oops...mysql server didn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-9215

When I logged into server then started Ambari , it works. But it is not working when I start using fabric.

Comment: As a work around, I am trying to push a script to the target host and executing the command in back ground.

My fabfile.py (task definition looks below)

@task
def start_Ambari_Server():
    put("/root/scripts/Start_Ambari.sh", "/tmp/Start_Ambari.sh")
    run('chmod 755 /tmp/Start_Ambari.sh')
    run('/tmp/Start_Ambari.sh')

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I am trying to push a script to the target host and executing the command in back ground.

And the content of /root/scripts/Start_Ambari.sh has below contents.

## !/bin/bash

ambari-server start &

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be anything for this case. Let me point out some of them and whichever works please let us know.

1. Run your ambari-server as root

   $sudo ambari-server start
2. Check your `/etc/hosts` file
3. Check if your 8080 port is opened for access.